# numpy non canonical dot product in higher dimension

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, tensordot

I'm trying to vectorize a loop with NumPy but I'm stuck
I have a matrix `A` of shape `(NN,NN)` I define the A-dot product by

```py
def scalA(u,v):
    return v.T @ A @ u
```

Then I have two matrices `B` and `C` (`B` has a shape `(N,NN)` and `C` has a shape `(K,NN)` the loop I'm trying to vectorize is

```py
res = np.zeros((N,K))
for n in range(N):
    for k in range(K):
        res[n,k] = scalA(B[n,:], C[k,:])
```

I found during my research functions like `np.tensordot` or `np.einsum`, but I haven't really understood how they work, and (if I have well understood) `tensordot` will compute the canonical dot product (that would correspond to `A = np.eye(NN)` in my case).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
np.einsum('ni,ji,kj->nk', B,A,C)
```

I think this works.  I wrote it 'by eye' without testing.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't... I get the `ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand 1`

Comment: actually if works on a small example with random matrix and gives the good result, it a problem on my code then... I will check on it !

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for this:

```
def scalA(u,v):
    return u @ A @ v.T
```

If shape of `A` is `(NN,NN)`, shape of `B` is `(N,NN)`, and shape of `C` is `(K,NN)`, the result of `scalA(B,C)` has shape `(N,K)`

If shape of `A` is `(NN,NN)`, shape of `B` is `(NN,)`, and shape of `C` is `(NN,)`, the result of `scalA(B,C)` is just a scalar.

However, if you're expecting `B` and `C` to have even higher dimensionality (greater than `2`), this may need further tweaking. (I could not tell from your question whether that's the case)

Comment: In my case B and C have 2 dimensions